# I have a probllem when the button delete has clicked but the data cannot delete and the url not show the id

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, crud

I have tried to solve this problem several hours but I never solve this problem

I have a problem with my code, when I click the delete button from json, I can't get the ID just link from the console like this:

example :

- That happened : `request`
- I want Like this : `request/?id=1`

I paste some code to check :

Controller `request.php`:

```
public function delete()
{
    // $this->m_request->delete($this->input->post('id_form'));
    $id = $this->input->post('id_form');
    $data = $this->m_request->DeleteRequest($id);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Model `m_request.php`:

```
public function DeleteRequest($id)
{
    $hasil = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM request WHERE id_form='$id'");
    return $hasil;
}
```

And Then View (I just put the modal script and ajax json script) :

Modal View :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalHapus" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Hapus Request</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">X</span></button>
        </div>
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="modal-body">

                <input type="hidden" name="kode" id="textkode" value="">
                <div class="alert alert-warning">
                    <p>Apakah Anda yakin mau menghapus request ini?</p>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button>
                <button class="btn_hapus btn btn-danger" id="btn_hapus">Hapus</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ajax/JSON Script :

```
 //GET HAPUS
    $(document).on('click', '.hapus', function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('data');
        $('#ModalHapus').modal('show');
        $('[name="kode"]').val(id);
    })

    // Hapus Request
    $('#btn_hapus').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $('textkode').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?= site_url('request/delete')?>",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {id:id},
            success: function(data){
                // $('#ModalHapus').modal('hide');
                console.log(data)
                load_data();
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
```

Comment: your `modal` is showing on click delete button?

Comment: and what you get in `console.log(data);`

Comment: on click delete button inside my `modal`, and i get `true` in `console.log(data);`, but the data is not deleted

Comment: what id does it contains  `var id = $('textkode').val();` `alert(id);`

Comment: change this `var id = $('textkode').val();` to `var id = $('#textkode').val();`

Comment: i got the `id`, but why the data still showing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of reasons why the ajax request is possibly not working. The first thing which came in my mind is, that you have not specified an ID and method of the input form. Make sure you have both in your HTML form tag. For example:

```
<form id=“id_form” method=“post” class=“...”>
...
    <input type="text" name="kode" id="textkode">
</form>
```

In you JS Code do the following

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?= site_url('request/delete')?>",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: $(“#id_form”).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
            load_data();
        }
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nERROR: "+ err);
        }
});
```

Also change the your delete function to this:

```
public function deleteTableRow()
{
    $id = $_POST['textkode'];  // Because I'm not sure what this->input->post() makes
    $result = $this->m_request->DeleteRequest($id);
    echo json_encode(array('id' => $id, 'result' => $result)); // The contents of array should then be displayed in the console of your webbrowser
}
```

Note that I changed the function name. It could be very misleading for other programmers, because delete is used in many programming languages as destructor for dynamic objects!

Additionally I would recommend to create an ajax.php file to parse different kind of ajax request. This file would also work as a controller, but just for ajax calls. In case you have several forms, the code is more readable.

Comment: Then it seems that the request worked, if the console displayed something. The reasons why it returns “true” could be that the SQL-query just returns true to your $data variable, which is sent afterwards to the client. The question is, what you want to return to the client side? If you just want to inform the client that a table row is delete this would be enough.

Comment: so what should i do?...i hope you will help me to solve this problem

Comment: I edited my answer, change your code according to it and please provide the output of your Webbrowser console log!

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/photos/185283344@N08/48971425656/in/dateposted-public/, 
You can check the link, because in that link you can see the results from `console.log` in Web Browser